# Spring Security 3.0 form-login Forwarding to External Resources

Tags: spring-security

Can the `form-login` tag make use of URLs to external resources?

I have two Web services running in separate application contexts [Case #1]. They could be on separate machines as well [Case #2].

I want the first service to use Spring Security to enforce authentication for certain methods. I want the second service to be used as the authenticating mechanism. If a request is not authenticated when it attempts to invoke a protected method on the first service, the request should be forwarded to the second service for authentication.

Both services are up and running. I have the first service configured and "working" except for the URL it forwards the request to when the user is not yet authenticated.

If the first Web service is located at `http://server1/community`, can Spring Security forward a user to a different service running in a separate context?

Ex:

```
<security:form-login 
    login-page="/auth/login.jsp" />
```

where `/auth` is the context of the second service.

Or, can it forward to a different server altogether?

```
<security:form-login 
    login-page="http://server2/auth/login.jsp" />
```

When I attempted the first configuration above, the URL forwarded to became `http://server1/community/auth/login.jsp`. I wanted `http://server1/auth/login.jsp`.

The second configuration yielded `http://server1/communityhttp://server2/auth/login.jsp`.

Clearly, the URLs are taken to be relative to the current context. Is there a way to change that behavior? Or, is there a better way to do what I am trying to do and I just haven't stumbled on it yet? ^__^

Thank you for your help!

-- JS

PS:  I posted this earlier as an "Answer" to a previous post by mistake.  Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is a way to do what you want.  The keyword that you need is `login-processing-url` on the `form-login` element.

Example:

```
<form-login login-page="/auth/login" login-processing-url="/auth/example_security_check"/>
```

Then in your jsp page you want to set the action to whatever you put there:

```
<form action="example_security_check" method="post">
    <label for="j_username">Login</label>:
    <input id="j_username" name="j_username" size="20" maxlength="50" type="text"/>
    <br/>

    <label for="j_password">Password</label>:
    <input id="j_password" name="j_password" size="20" maxlength="50" type="password"/>
    <br/>

    <input type="submit" value="Login"/>
    <br/>
    <br/>

    <input id="_spring_security_remember_me" name="_spring_security_remember_me" type="checkbox" value="true"/>
    <label for="_spring_security_remember_me">Remember Me?</label>
</form>
```

The documentation for the attribute is here

http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/appendix-namespace.html

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can overwrite the class LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint and instead of using the  tag, you manually add the required elements to the configuration

See [form-login doku](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/appendix-namespace.html#nsa-form-login) for the required elements.
its only the UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter and the LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint.
I guess you can use the custom-filter tag to add the filter.